# Mesh intersection in three.js after modifying vertices/position

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a mesh inited with plane geometry with placeholder parameters (like xyz 0, wh 100).

Later I set actual position for the mesh and 4 vertices for the geometry, and it renders fine.

However when I try to intersect the mesh with raycaster, I get intersections only where it was inited, not where it's rendered after parameters were set.

What should I call after vertices/position update for the mesh to be intersectable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recompute the geometries boundingBox and/or boundingSphere using computeBoundingBox() and/or computeBoundingSphere() method. This should do the trick